# What is the name for the date number for a given day? Days of the month?

Tags: dates

I know that Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc. are days of the week. Is there a similar term for "days of the month"?

E.g., "Monday the 7th" has "Monday" as a weekday and "7th" as the "day of the month"? Or is it called something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Day of the month" is understandable here.

> What day of the month are we paid?
>
> On the third.

In some contexts "date" would also be understood

> What is the date of the Christmas party?
>
> It's on the nineteenth.     ["of December" is understood from context]

Comment: Thank you! But is there a parallel term to "days of the week"? Should simply "date" be used instead to get the number of the day?

Comment: @flen  I don't want to repeat myself, but the answer to the question' is there a parallel term to "days of the week"?' is written above in the first sentence.  And the answer to 'Should simply "date" be used?' is written above in the second sentence and example.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being very clear. My question was actually whether "day of the month" can always be understood or if it was only understood in some particular contexts, like the one of your first example. But your comment cleared it up for me, I should use "day of the month", but date can also be used in some contexts